# Bus-powered non-USB device (like fan,lamp) USB pin arrangement to getting highest power from USB host

Tags: power-supply, usb, embedded

Bus powered means device that only use Vbus of USB for it's power supply. I want to use micro USB as my board power supply. The is designed to take 600mA by 3.3v regulator. But I just don't know how to behave to it's pins?
I have found [somewhere](http://pinoutguide.com/ChargersAdapters/micro_usb_charger_pinout.shtml) that, it's data pins must shorted or connected together through 0-200 ohm resistor.

[image]

What and why must be exactly it's resistor?

How must be behaved to it's "shield" and "ID" pins? GND must be simply gnd isn't that?

how it will behave to charger and PCs?

### Update:

I've found [some](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5801) nice theory about chargers beacon, for telling to hosts: I have XmA (X is variable) current available. Then they adapt themselves to accept that power. It means host will detect chargers available power.

But I want my board to beacon to the host like this: Hey host I want lot's of power please give me 1.5A (dedicated charge port) if possible.

[image: Charger beacon types]
Ok, but my question is on the suppliant side not the supplier.I want good wiring configuration for:

(1)Ability to take required current from every supply including PCs without digital enumeration through MCU. (And is there any wiring config to get ride of enumeration?) (2)Nice noise, EMI, EMC performance

I've also asked my question in other form [here](https://ez.analog.com/power/f/q-a/105409/getting-1-5a-from-usb-host-without-enumeration).

Comment: You're over thinking this.  For 600 mA draw and personal use, just wire it up and be careful that you only plug it into "charger" supplies of sufficient rating.  Pretty obviously you are not making a product to sell to others, or at least you should not be as are nowhere near ready to do so.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes this is prototype for learning, But if I connected it to PC USB then what will happening? this will go to suspend mode, isn't?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of misunderstanding. The short between D+ and D- (resistor less than 200 Ohms) is the [signature](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/271681/117785) of USB Battery Charging 1.2 Dedicated Charging Port on the SIDE OF CHARGER. On device (consumer) side you don't need this. In best case you should attempt to detect the short in order to determine if the port is capable of charging above the default USB power (500 mA or 900 mA).

ID has no relevance in the case of device, and shield can be safely tied with ground.

If your device consumes up to 600 mA at 3.3 V, you can design a switching-type voltage regulator (SMPS buck converter) instead of LDO. The SMPS will transform consumed current, so on the 5-V side it will consume under 500 mA (accounting for 85-90% efficiency). In this case you should not worry about USB port limitations, and your device will be happy with nearly any USB port.

Comment: Thx for answer. (1) you mean: D+/D- wiring is in supply(charger or PC) side and states how it can provide a current to the device. Finally there is no beacon in the device to tell the supply: I am compatible for XA of current? (2) Is there any recommendation for state of "ID", in charger mod, to float it or resistor/short it to gnd/vcc?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd, (1) - yes, bur not sure what your "XA" is; (2) ID pin in classic USB is always an input, it was meant to discriminate between micro-A and micro-B type of plugs, and was never "propagated" from source to destination, unlike CC wires in newer Type-C connection standard. Leave ID unconnected.

Comment: For correctness: 500mA is allowed only after enumeration — the idea is that a hub that itself only has 500mA on the input side will reject configuring your device because it would run out.

Comment: XA meant desirable amount of X current value in A(ampere). But I've heard: Do not leave any pin float, (1) still you think I must leave it float? (2) How I must enumerate for desired current? is it possible with MCU? I've tried to learn enumeration from USB_2 specs from USB-IF but I can't find @USB Interface Power Management Specification@ as it told: "The INTERFACE_POWER descriptor is defined in the current revision of the USB Interface Power Management Specification."? (3) The only way to give desired current from host is digitally enumerating? sorry because of long story!

Comment: As I think I had badly  explained my question if you think it`s better to split the question I will appreciate it.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd, since you are not making a USB device, you don't need to have any enumeration,  see this answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/382319/117785 or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/361929/117785 and this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/314188/117785

Comment: I've also added update to my question. You could also read this new extension, please. Also 7.2.1 of USB spec was helpful thx.

Comment: Thanks for good answers. Then this is not USB device, ok. Now I wanna connect my power consumer to USB host, how host will behave, will it go to suspend due to lack of digital connection? There is no way to force host to operate in DCP or at least high-power port (I think high-power meaning less {because this is not USB device!} but may DCP can be possible) ??

Answer (score 0):

> What and why must be exactly it's resistor?

See [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123172/what-is-the-ideal-way-to-handle-data-pins-d-and-d-on-a-usb-power-adapter-to-be), in short it is for fast charging. This is beyond the original spec of 500mA for USB so YMMV.

> How must be behave to it's "shield" and "ID" pins? GND must be simply
>   gnd isn't that?

ID is for USB "On the go" (OTG) and detection of a device or host.
Shield connects to the outer conductor of the cable or shield. The shield is to be connected to the chassis (in general if you have one). It can also be tied to ground, but this can also create problems, so you'd need to do some EMC research depending on what your device actually is.

> how it will behave to charger and PCs?

PC's can only source 500mA, fast chargers can source more.

Comment: Thx for answer. (1) you mean: D+/D- wiring is in supply(charger or PC) side and states how it can provide a current to the device. Finally there is no beacon in the device to tell the supply: I am compatible for XA of current? (2) Is there any recommendation for state of "ID", in charger mod, to float it or resistor/short it to gnd/vcc?